# Child activity from ActivityGroup just "sometimes" calling onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, activitygroup

I have an `ActivityGroup` with several child Activities.

Recently I discovered that the `onBackPressed` method is not always being called on the child Activities but in the parent Activity (the activityGroup).

After some testing I discovered that the `onBackPressed` is only invoked on the children when they have a focused EditText. If the EditText is not focused or if there is no EditText (even if there are other controls such as buttons or checkboxes) then it won't be called after all.

If the child receives this invocation, then the parent doesn't.

Does anyone know why the behavior of the Activity changes? Is there some method I can execute on the child Activity so that it always gains this focus and gains the `onBackPressed` method preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest implementation was to create a method that was called either by the parent->currentChild or by the child when the back button was pressed.

Comment: thank you htafoya... I faced the same issue in my application. I resolved the issue with this post.

Answer (score 0):

New year wishes to you too htafoya....make sure you have defined onBackPressed function outside onCreate function. Many times it happens you have declared onBackPressed within the onCreate function's loop.